# building app for android 2.3 using cordova version 4

Tags: android, cordova

I want to build app for android 2.3 which is not supported to by latest cordova version 6. So I have installed cordova version 4 which did support compling for this version of android. I am on Linux

I have changed `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

everything goes right until last step `cordova compile android` and I get huge log of error in terminal.

Log file: http://pastebin.com/qcqvH3sF
AndroidManifest.xml file: http://pastebin.com/5LppSD8x

```
$  cordova -v
4.3.1
$  cordova platforms ls
Installed platforms: android 3.7.2
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, ubuntu
```

I really need to build android for older version too because many people around me are still using older version. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to work with the 2.3.3 (API 10) platform then you can always install a specific platform version like this:

`cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@2.3.3`

Comment: it is giving me error: `Unable to fetch platform android@2.3.3: Error: version not found: 2.3.3 : cordova-android/2.3.3`

Comment: Ouch. Not sure of the location on other platforms but for Windows, I'd check `C:\Users\<username>\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android` to see if 2.3.3 is listed. If not, perhaps try an earlier version of Cordova.